# In List form when user click on save button item save two times?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

In List form, I added one new button as save and send. When user click on this button, I fire this event to save the list item.

> $('input['name*="IOsaveItem"]'.click()

But it save two times item.

This issue in only IE.

Comment: Why you fire click event? SharePoint will fire after execute PreSave function.

Comment: Please read my question I modify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are `2 Save button` in form. 
One button is on top that is not visible. Your script is firing 2 Save button click event.

Try with below syntax:

> $('input[id*="IOSaveItem"][id*="BarTbl_"]').trigger( "click" );

Comment: Great.. Yr welcome.